# How to handle specific error messages in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, scrapy

Sometimes I get the following message:

```
in process_item item['external_link_rel'] = dict_["rel"]
KeyError: 'rel'
```

It must be because it doesn't exist.
I tried to manage but failed.

‍

```
from lxml import etree
```

class CleanItem():

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    try:
        root = etree.fromstring(str(item['external_link_body']).split("'")[1])
        dict_ = {}
        dict_.update(root.attrib)
        dict_.update({'text': root.text})
        item['external_link_rel'] = dict_["rel"]
        return item
   
    except KeyError as EmptyVar:
        if str(EmptyVar) == 'rel': 
            dict_["rel"] = "null"
            item['external_link_rel'] = dict_["rel"]
            return item
```

‍

Most likely, all problems are due to this line `if str(EmptyVar) == 'rel'`.

Thank you for guiding me so that an operation is performed only when this error occurs.

Before asking the question, I did a lot of research and did not come to a conclusion

Just for information, the above codes are in the pipelines.py file inside the Scrapy framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do it is to use the dictionary attribute `get`. You can read on it [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html)

```
from lxml import etree

class CleanItem():
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        root = etree.fromstring(str(item['external_link_body']).split("'")[1])
        dict_ = {}
        dict_.update(root.attrib)
        dict_.update({'text': root.text})
        item['external_link_rel'] = dict_.get("rel", "null")
        return item
```

Comment: Can you help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73389010/8519380

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a conditional statement?

```
from lxml import etree

class CleanItem():
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        root = etree.fromstring(str(item['external_link_body']).split("'")[1])
        dict_ = {}
        dict_.update(root.attrib)
        dict_.update({'text': root.text})
        if 'rel' not in dict_:            # If 'rel' is not a key in dict
           dict_["rel"] = "null"          
           item['external_link_rel'] = dict_["rel"]  
           return item                    
        item['external_link_rel'] = dict_["rel"]  # else ...
        return item
```

If you really wanted to use try/except clauses you could do this.
I would never recommend using try/except where it isn't necessary though.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    root = etree.fromstring(str(item['external_link_body']).split("'")[1])
    dict_ = {}
    dict_.update(root.attrib)
    dict_.update({'text': root.text})
    try:
        item['external_link_rel'] = dict_["rel"]
        return item
    except KeyError:
        dict_["rel"] = "null"
        item['external_link_rel'] = dict_["rel"]
        return item
```

Comment: thanks, Can't it be done with try/except command?

Comment: @sardar Sure it could.  but then you are raising an exception and catching it, which creates unnecessary overhead and makes the code less readable as well.

Comment: @Sardar  see update to answer for an example.

Comment: There is a challenge, whenever a KeyError occurs that exception is thrown, and it may not be a KeyError for rel.

Comment: that is why the conditional expression is a much better solution.  otherwise you would need to raise the exception yourself with a message in which case you would still be using a conditional expression

Comment: Can you help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73389010/8519380